# How to implement semaphores in PHP without PHP Semaphore?

Tags: php, wordpress, locking, deadlock, semaphore

**Question:**

How can I implement shared memory variable in PHP without the semaphore package (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-get-var.php) ?

**Context**

- I have a simple web application (actually a plugin for WordPress)
- this gets a url
- this then checks the database if that url already exists
- if not then it goes out and does some operations
- and then writes the record in the database with the url as unique entry

What happens in reality is that 4,5,6 ... sessions at the same time request the url and I get up to 9 duplicate entries in the database of the url.. (possibly 9 because the processing time and database write of the first entry takes just enough time to let 9 other requests fall through). After that all requests read the correct entry that the record already exists so that is good.

Since it is a WordPress plugin there will be many users on all kind of shared hosting platforms with variable compiles/settings of PHP.

So I'm looking for a more generic solution. I cant use database or text file writes since these will be too slow. while i write to the db the next session will already have passed.

fyi: the database code: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-favicons/trunk/includes/server/plugins/metadata_favicon/inc/class-favicon.php

**update**

Using a unique key on a new md5 hash of the uri together with try catches around it seems to work.

I found 1 duplicate entry with

```
SELECT uri, COUNT( uri ) AS NumOccurrences
FROM edl40_21_wpfavicons_1
GROUP BY uri
HAVING (
COUNT( uri ) >1
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

So I thought it did not work but this was because they were:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_dead
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Dead
```

(capitals grin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved with MySQL.

You could do it explicitly by locking the table from read access. This will prevent any read access from the entire table though, so may not be preferable. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html

Otherwise if the field in the table is classified as unique, then when the next session tries to write the same URL to the table they will get an error, you can catch that error and continue as there's no need to do anything if the entry is already there. The only time wasted is the possibility of two or more sessions creating the same URL, the result is still one record, as the database won't add the same unique URL again.

As discussed in comments, because the length of a URL could be very long, and fixed length unique hash can help overcome that issue.

Comment: It is a big of extra storage, but perhaps you could use a unique hash instead?

Comment: locking the complete table is a bit harsh, during 1 lock I probably have around N processes not being able to write (from different uris). In can not make uri unique: there is a max length for unique fields. a unique hash is interesting maybe that is what delicious also does. here you see intermixing db requests: http://leau.co/wp-content/blogs.dir/21/files/wp-favicons/cache/DEBUG.LOG

Comment: since i do not know if a uri record exists it probably goes like this (A) update LOCK in record where uri_hash=md5(uri) try catch (B) read if it exists (C) if it exists release  A (D) if not exist do processing, write and release A - lemme try that :)

Comment: Yea locking will hold up any further requests. I would try the unique hash approach and let MySQL prevent adding duplicates. Interesting issue.

Comment: the problem with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109825/how-to-impliment-a-read-then-write-lock-in-mysql is that during a read the result is that the record does not exist. if it does not exist there is nothing to lock and N sessions begin processing all wanting to write but that would be solved by setting the hash unique. but i still have n processes running. Possible i can prevent that by always trying an insert with a try catch. and in the catch handle the php logic and set a bool... have to think this through lol.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother locking... The processing will be the same for each unique URI, so first check, if its not there, process it and try and add it. If in that time it has been added, then you handle the mysql error.

Comment: hmm... still wont work bit complicated... a uri can have a unique favicon uri... but if another uri has the same favicon uri it points to the original uri to prevent duplication... IF that original uri does not exist (yet) i will have multiple unique uri's but duplicate favicon urls.... GRIN argh. and the favicon uri is only known during processing since it can be a lot of things. have to think this through more.

Comment: but this another problem/pattern transactions wont work here. I think i need an intermediate table with timestamps that gets processed to another table after some time.

Answer (score 1):

There are other shared memory modules in PHP ([shmop](http://us.php.net/shmop) or [APC](http://us.php.net/apc) for example), but I think what you are saying is that there is an issue relying on non-standard/not pre-installed libraries.

My suggestion is that before you go and do "other operations" you need to make an entry in the database, perhaps with a status of "compiling" (or something) so you know it is still not available. This way you don't run into issues with getting multiple entries. I would also be sure you are using transactions when they are available so your commits are atomic.

Then, when you "other operations" are done, update the database entry to "available" and do whatever else it is you need to do.